# Installing oci8 extension in linux for php?

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I don't have a oracle database installed in my system. But i want to connect to the remote system. Do i just need to install oci8 extension library or i need to install both instantclient and the oci8 extension?

Comment: Is there any thing wrong in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, OCI8 extension wouldn't even compile without Instant Client; if you install using [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8), it asks you for Instant Client path. Moreover, from my experience, you'll also need Instant Client **SDK** in addition to Basic, unpack them to one directory, and make some symlinks before running PECL command:

```
sudo ln -s libclntsh.so.* libclntsh.so
sudo ln -s libocci.so.* libocci.so
```

Don't forget to enable the config later:

```
echo "; configuration for php oci8 module" | sudo tee /etc/php5/conf.d/oci8.ini
echo extension=oci8.so | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/conf.d/oci8.ini
```

Taken from [this post](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116474/) (in Russian), also installed OCI8 myself recently on Debian 7.